# Implement Bidirectional Infinite ScrellView in react-native

Tags: react-native, infinite-scroll

I want to implement infinite scrollview in both the direction. Also the data should be loaded dynamically.

I am using *SectionList* component for list. I have implemented forward infinite scrolling. That means if user scroll down, the data will append to list automatically.

For that I have used *onMomentumScrollEnd* event. When user stops the scrolling, if the scroll is in Up direction, data will be appended at the End and if the scroll is in Down direction, data will be appended at the Top.

Now the problem is when I append the data at Top of list, It shift all the current list data to backward. I don't want to shift the current list even if the data is updated. Is there any way to do it.

This is my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    SectionList,
} from 'react-native';
import CardComponent from './CardComponent'

export default class Schedule extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          sectionData: [],
          loading: false,
        }
        this.contentOffsetY = 0;
        this._onScroll = this._onScroll.bind(this)
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ sectionData: this.props.data })
    }
    
    renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <CardComponent
            data={item}
            key={item}
        />
    );
    
    renderDateSeparator(text) {
        return (
            <Text style={{
                    paddingVertical: 15,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    flex: 1,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    textAlignVertical: 'center',
                }}>
               {text}
            <Text>
        )
    }
    
    _onScroll(e){
        let contentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        this.contentOffsetY < contentOffset ? this.loadMoreOnBottom() : this.loadMoreOnTop();
        this.contentOffsetY = contentOffset;
    }
    
    loadMoreOnTop() {
      this.setState({ lodaing: true });
      // code to append data on top of list
      this.setState({ lodaing: false });
    }
    
    loadMoreOnBottom() {
      // code to append data at bottom of list
    }
    
    render() {
      const sectionData = this.state.sectionData;
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <SectionList
                onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onScroll}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                itemShouldUpdate={false}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                renderSectionHeader={({section}) => this.renderDateSeparator(section.date)}
                sections={sectionData}
                stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                refreshing={this.state.loading}
                onRefresh={() => this.loadMoreOnTop()}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
                onEndReached={() => this.loadMoreOnBottom()}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            />
        </View>
      )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After so much of research, I have finally implemented the bidirectional infinite scroll view in react-native.

For the implementation, I have replaced my `SectionList` with `FlatList`, Because I want to use *scrollToOffset* method which is not properly working in SectionList.

I have used `setInterval` function of javaScript. It regularly checks weather the list need to be append from top or bottom.

This is my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import CardComponent from './CardComponent'

let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Schedule extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          listData: [],
        }
        this.contentOffsetY = 0;
        this.pageOffsetY = 0;
        this.contentHeight = 0;
        
        this._onScroll = this._onScroll.bind(this);
        this.loadMoreOnTop = this.loadMoreOnTop.bind(this);
        this.loadMoreOnBottom = this.loadMoreOnBottom.bind(this);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ listData: this.props.data });
        this._interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ load: true });
        }, 2000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this._interval);
    }

    renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <CardComponent
            data={item}
            key={item}
        />
    );
    
    _onScroll(e){
        let contentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        this.contentOffsetY < contentOffset ? this.loadMoreOnBottom() : this.loadMoreOnTop();
        this.contentOffsetY = contentOffset;
    }
        
    scrollToOffset = (offset) => {
        this.flatListRef ? this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({animated: false, offset}) : null;
    };

    loadMoreOnTop() {
      let newOffset;
      
      // code to append data on top of list
      
      // calculate newOffset:
      newOffset = this.pageOffsetY + space required for new data.

      this.contentOffsetY = newOffset;
      this.scrollToOffset(newOffset);
    }
    
    loadMoreOnBottom() {
      // code to append data at bottom of list
    }
    
    render() {
      const listData = this.state.listData;
      
      if(this.pageOffsetY < 600) {
          this.loadMoreOnTop();
      } else if((this.contentHeight - this.pageOffsetY) < (height * 1.5)){
          this.loadMoreOnBottom();
      }
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <FlatList
                onScroll={(e) => {
                    this.pageOffsetY = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
                    this.contentHeight = e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
                    return null;
                }}
                onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onScroll}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                itemShouldUpdate={false}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                data={listData}
                refreshing={false}
                onRefresh={() => this.loadMoreOnTop()}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
                onEndReached={() => this.loadMoreOnBottom()}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
                ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
                animated={false}
            />
        </View>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I'm exactly building the same list as you, but I'd like to know how do you calculate `space required for new data`? Are you rows fixed heights? Because my rows have different heights for each item, it's hard to know how many heights I gained after loading a bunch of rows.

Comment: Yes I have given fix space for each row. But if you have dynamic row height, then you need to calculate the height based on the new data received. Calculation of the space required by new data is essential for smooth scrolling experience.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Do you have any experience of calculating dynamic height rows? Or do you have any hint? All I can think of is to collect the height of rows after they are mounted, but it seems tedious to do so, I'm wondering if there are better ways?

Comment: @MarsonMao Any workaround or solution for this dynamic height rows? still facing in 2021

Comment: @SungHoChoi Sorry I havent been implementing this for a long time, already lost all the memories. Wish you luck!

Comment: @MarsonMao No problem! Thank you for the response